# Spring MVC Navigation between jsp's

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am using Java 8 and Spring 5.1.5. I am new to this so have tried to follow the guidelines but have a problem in that the DispatcherServlet and/or Controller mapping seems to be skipped, I get the following error in Tomcat:

The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

My web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
                             id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

        <description>
            Configuration file for the Store Application
        </description>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
        </listener>

        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/Store-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>

        <servlet>
          <servlet-name>Store</servlet-name>
          <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>        
          <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value></param-value>
          </init-param>
          <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>Store</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

My Store-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:context = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation = "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package = "com.store.controller" />
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
      <property name = "prefix" value = "/WEB-INF/jsp" />
      <property name = "suffix" value = ".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>

</beans>
```

My Controller

```
package com.store.controller;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;


@Controller
public class CarMartController {

    private transient Logger log = Logger.getLogger( "CarMartController" );


    @GetMapping("/store/carMart")
    public String navigateToCarMart( ModelMap model) {
        log.info("CarMartController [navigatetoCarMart");
        return "carMart";
    }
}
```

My CarMart.jsp and header

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>

<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resources/css/styles.css" />
        <title>Car Mart</title>
    </head>
    <body style="background-image:url(/resources/images/carBackground.jpg);background-size:cover">
        <jsp:include page="./header.jsp" />
    </body>
</html>

<%@ taglib prefix="c"   uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
 <div class="navbar">
    <a href="<c:url value='/customer/customerDetail.jsp' />" >Customers</a>
    <a href="<c:url value='/car/carDetail.jsp' />" >Cars</a>
</div>
```

The URL I am calling with is http://localhost:8088/store/carMart.jsp

The Resources directory is in the webapps/store directory of the war file

The jsp directory is in the WEB-INF directory

Comment: Use http://localhost:8088/store/carMart to access your endpoint, (**without .jsp at the end**)

Comment: Hi, I have changed the servlet-name in web.xml from Store to store, no change.

Comment: Hi, I tried calling as localhost:8088/store/carMart and got No mapping for GET /store/carMart error

Comment: Hi, please check the answer - it should probably help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, add `@RequestMapping` for your controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/store")
public class CarMartController {

    @GetMapping("/carMart")
    public String navigateToCarMart( ModelMap model) {
    ...
    }

}
```

And try to access your endpoint using: http://localhost:8088/store/carMart
Without **.jsp** at the end.

Comment: Hi, got it, I have changed the controller as suggested and also added <mvc:annotation-driven/> and it works, the DispatcherServlet is calling my controller which in turn generates the view carMart.jsp. There is still a problem with finding the resources directory

Comment: This is probably a subject for another question.

Comment: Add more logs to your question so we can understand what's going on.

Comment: I am happy that this question has been answered, thanks guys, I will raise another to deal with resources

Answer (score 0):

The comments regarding RequestMapping and adding the

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

fixed the problem